# Add only some polylines from Kml file

Tags: c#, bing-maps, polyline

I developed a Windows Store application with Bing Maps. I have to add polylines from kml file to the map but only the polylines that are inside a specific radius from my position.

Now I use the library SharpKml to parse the files and add all the polylines.

How can I add only some lines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is some piece of metadata available in the KML file, you can then filter the lines based on that information.